# C - freeing struct containing a 2d array

Tags: c, struct, free

```
#define LEVEL_MAX_WIDTH 25
#define LEVEL_MAX_HEIGHT 12

typedef struct Level 
{
    Cell cells[LEVEL_MAX_HEIGHT][LEVEL_MAX_WIDTH]; /* Cell is also a struct */
    int width;
    int height;
} Level; 

void level_free(Level* level)
{
    /* Free cells*/
    for (int i = 0; i < level->height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < level->width; j++) {
            free(level->cells[i][j]);
        }
    }
    free(level);
}
```

When I was debugging my `level_Free(Level*)` method, I noticed something odd.

During the first iteration `(i=0 and j=0)`, after the method `free(level->cells[i][j]` was called: all the other cells in `level->[i]` were deallocated.

Freeing one Cell-element resulted into freeing the whole array where this element is part of.

Can anyone provide explanation why this happened?

EDIT:
This is how I "create" my cells:

```
            Cell* cell = malloc(sizeof(Cell)); 
            cell->row = r;
            cell->col = c;
            cell->type=level_symbol_to_cell_type(symbol);
            cell->owner=level_symbol_to_owner(symbol);
            /* place cell */
            level->cells[r][c] = *cell;

typedef struct Cell 
{
    int row;
    int col;
    CellType type; /* enum */
    Owner owner; /* enum also */
} Cell;
```

Comment: There isn't anything to free here, unless `Cell` is typedeffed to a pointer to the struct. If `Cell` is just a struct, your `Level` struct holds all data. You probably don't `malloc` anything either, do you? And how do you know that "the other ceels were deallocated"?

Comment: I don't even understand how you observed / why you thought the elements were deallocated.

Comment: You have to provide more context as none can answer the question just by looking at that function alone.

Comment: That needs a bunch of additional code context to be solveable me thinks. It partially hinges on how your `cell` struct is defined.

Comment: Before the loop I saved the adresses of all cells. After the first free() call, I checked the values of all those adresses and noticed they lost their value.

Comment: @Domien: What you're saying makes no sense. Post complete code.

Comment: I added the part of my code where I alloc my cells.

Answer (score 1):

You should not individually free the members of the array, if each Cell is a struct rather than a pointer to dynamically allocated memory.

You need to dynamically deallocate memory that you've dynamically allocated. If you've `malloc`'d a Level, you need to `free` it.

But the memory for the array, and its members, are in the block of memory allocated for a Level. You note in a comment that Cell is a struct. The memory for each Cell is therefore included in the block of memory allocated for the Level, and is disposed of by freeing the Level.

```
void level_free(Level* level)
{
    free(level);
}
```

Your edit shows that a Cell itself points to no dynamically allocated memory. *If instead it did,* you would have to free that as well.

```
void level_free(Level* level)
{
    /* Free cells*/
    for (int i = 0; i < level->height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < level->width; j++) {
            cell_free( & level->cells[i][j]);
        }
    }
    free(level);
}

void cell_free( Cell * level) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: So free(level) will be enough to deallocate the level pointer and all of its contents?

Comment: "don't need individually free" is confusing; it sounds as if "you can free it if you feel diligent". If you free something you don't need to free, there is undefined behavior, which can account for "all other elements being freed".

Comment: @Domien - It depends on whether or not there is any dynamically allocated memory pointed to (and owned) by the contents. If not, `free(level)` will be sufficient. But if there is, you also have to free the dynamically allocated memory pointed to within the contents.

Comment: You really should ask for clarification first. It's a messy question bound to attract messy answers. Feeling a great urge to downvote.

Comment: @Domien - If you post the struct definition of Cell, we could be more specific.

Comment: Added the struct definition also :)

Comment: @Domien - Thank you. Do either CellType or Owner hold any pointers to dynamically allocated memory, directly within their struct, or indirectly through some contents of the struct?

Comment: Sorry forgot to say they are both enums. So no they don't have alllocated memory. :)

Comment: I think I made a memory leak when doing:  level->cells[r][c] = *cell;
Since the original cell pointer is lost after the function ends, right?

Comment: Since a Cell has no pointers, you can use simple assignment to copy one cell to the other. Once the assigment is complete, it doesn't matter what happens to that pointer on the right-hand-side of the assignment.

Comment: But the cell pointer (on the right-hand-side) is allocated like this: Cell* cell = malloc(sizeof(Cell)); 
Later, when I write " level->cells[r][c] = *cell" . Won't the cell value be copied, resulting in 2 memory locations for the same cell?

Comment: This sounds like it may merit a separate stackoverflow question. From your last two comments, it sounds as if you're dynamically allocating a cell in a function, then copying its value to a member of the array, then leaving the method. (Pardon me if I misunderstand.) This would be how we would do things in Java, where all objects are dynamically allocated and referenced with pointers ("references"). But in C, not all memory is dynamically allocated or referenced with pointers. If you're trying to fill a Cell in the Level within a method, you can just fill it. The Cell instance already exists.

Answer (score 0):

You should `free` only pointers to dynamically allocated memory, otherwise the behavior is undefined.
If you dynamically allocated memory for `Level` then freeing just the returned pointer would free the array too.